# Intel AppFramework overlay menu

Tags: appframework

I am new to Intel's APPFramework

At present  Side Menu is working like Push. Is there an **overlay** option available or need to modify the css to achieve overlay side menu

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is only push.  App Framework 3.0 https://github.com/01org/appframework/tree/3.0beta has more transitions (overaly, push, reveal).

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/30

Also, it's not modifying CSS.  It uses JavaScript for animation (due to Android 2.3 support).  https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/master/ui/appframework.ui.js#L701

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try it with the above provided link